# Cannot access Spring Boot application running on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, networking, amazon-ec2, routes

I have a Spring Boot application running on port `8080` on an Amazon EC2 instance. Both commands work when executed on the instance:

```
curl localhost:8080
curl ec2-<public-ip>.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080
```

However, the latter command doesn't work on my computer. The inbound rules seem to be alright. What else could be the problem?

Inbound rules:

[image: Inbound rules]

Comment: You don't give much details on your infra, but could be that the application is bound to the loopback interface of your instance

Comment: How could I check if this is the case?

Comment: have you found issue?